# The 32-bit Win 7 Trial can be downloaded but 64-bit cannot. Anyone see that same issue?

Tags: windows-7, download, certificate

On

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx

the 32-bit Win 7 Trial can be downloaded but 64-bit cannot.  Does anyone see that same issue?

**Update:**

I tried IE 8, FF 3.5, and Chrome

the error I see on FF 3.5 is

> wb.dlservice.microsoft.com uses an
>   invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for
>   a248.e.akamai.net
>
> (Error code:
>   ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

IE 8 has the same issue.  Chrome has no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your update: The error you're seeing on Firefox simply indicates that the domain name on the SSL certificate doesn't match the domain name on the site. Since you're not giving them any information (e.g. submitting a form), you can probably just ignore the error. There should be an "Add exception" button or something like that when you see the warning in Firefox, that you can click on to proceed.  (You can search the web for detailed instructions on adding a certificate security exception in Firefox 3)

Comment: thanks but right now cannot ignore the error since there is no download at all.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, try a different browser:

[image]

I'm on Firefox 3.5.3.

---

**Edit:**

That error is because the certificate assigned to the web server belongs to another domain. You can temporarily add a security exception, Microsoft just didn't set that up very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/c7e63159-3c4d-48fb-afd9-c5891b101e99

We haven't got anywhere with Microsoft correcting their error yet, but this is the most likely place to see if it has been fixed!